# SSL cert on new IIS web server

Tags: iis, ssl

I just had a server die on me and I wasn't able to export the SSL certificate to the new server. Can I install the .pfx file from the original webserver to the new one or do I need to generate a new certificate?

Comment: You should be able to just go to the authoritative host and re-download it.  If it's self signed, just generate a new one.

Comment: Hi George. Do i select the option 'Import a certificate from .pfx'?

Comment: If you create the certificate, you'll need to import that into your cert store.  Once in your personal (MY) store, you'll want to use "Assign an existing certificate".  If you imported it correctly, it will appear as a selectable cert.

Comment: @george - there's no need to do that when importing a SSL certificate into IIS 6 or IIS7. You can use the tooling and wizard in IIS manager without touching the Cert Store and it'll do the "right thing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just import the original SSL to the new server without any fussing around generating new CSR's or touching the certificate store directly.

Use the "Import a certificate from a .pfx file" option in the IIS Certificate Wizard (if you're using IIS6):

[image]

If this is IIS7 you need to import the SSL using the Server Certificates feature in IIS Manager (which exists at the server level branch of the tree):

[image]

To assign the certificate to a site you need to edit the site's bindings and choose the certificate from the list available:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Copy the certificate from the original server to your new server:

1. On a server that has the SSL certificate, open IIS.
2. In the Connections pane (on the left) select the server.
3. In the middle pane open Server Certificates.
4. Right-click the certificate and select Export…
5. Export the certificate to a .pfx file and provide a password.
6. Copy the .pfx file to the server that needs the new certificate.
7. In IIS on the 2nd server, open IIS and go to Server Certificates.
8. In the Actions pane (on the right) click Import...
9. Browse to the .pfx file and enter its password.
10. Ensure the bindings in the websites get updated to use the new certificate.